# Removing a value from an array stored in Mongo document

Tags: mongodb

I have a document in a Mongo collection which looks something like this:

```
{
  _id: [uuid]
  prop: 
    some: "text",
    subprop: ['foo', 'bar']
}
```

I'd like to avoid having to pull the whole record out, modify it and push it back if that's possible. What update can I run to have `'bar'` removed from `doc.prop.subprop`, not knowing the index it's stored at?

Thanks :)

Comment: Doesn't `$pull` do this: `db.col.update({}, {$pull:{'prop.subprop': 'bar'}})` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the $pull operator, which can pull a specific value from a field. You can use dot notation to get the subprop field:

```
db.foo.update( { _id : [uuid] }, { $pull : { "prop.subprop" : "bar" } } );
```

If you want to run the update for multiple documents in the collection, you'll need to set multi : true in your query with the following syntax:

```
db.foo.update( { _id : [uuid] }, { $pull : { "prop.subprop" : "bar" } }, { multi : true } );
```

This means that the update query will run on all documents that match { _id : [uuid] } in your collection.

Comment: Perfect thanks very much :) Tried going through every operator in the docs, but that one must have missed me :)